# Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Webapplication1.models.Enrollment'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to compute the grade point average of a student from the database and select the computed value and send to the views to the client which requested for their result, but I got this error which is shown below.

I'm trying to respond to a request from a submitted form by a student user. With the linq query below I computed the GPA of the student and selected it so to display the student information and GPA to view for a student, but I'm getting the problem of cannot convert anonymous type to the model.

Please can you help me on how to the anonymous type to the model class below?

```
Enrollment Request = (from a in db.Enrollments
                      where a.StudentProfile.Matric_Number ==
                          e.StudentProfile.Matric_Number &&
                          a.Academic_SessionId == e.Academic_SessionId &&
                          a.SemesterId == e.SemesterId

                      join b in db.Courses on a.CourseId equals b.CourseId
                      join c in db.StudentProfiles on a.StudentId equals c.StudentId
                      group a by a.StudentProfile.Matric_Number into g
                      let GPA = (decimal)(g.Sum(a => a.GradePoint * a.Course.Credit) / 
                          g.Sum(a => a.Course.Credit))
                      select new { GPA }).SingleOrDefault();
```

ENROLLMENT TABLE

```
EnrollmentId
Academic sessionId
StudentId
CourseId
LetterGrade
LecturerId
SemesterId
GradePoint
Scores
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned in my earlier comment, you can't add the GPA to the entity model, because it doesn't represent a database column.  You are treating it as a *computed* property.  So you have a couple of choices.

One, you can return a decimal from your query that represents just the GPA:

```
decimal Request = (...
                      select new GPA).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can also create a ***new*** `Enrollment` model in a different namespace than your entity model that includes the `GPA` property.  These are sometimes referred to as `Data Transfer Objects`.

```
select new DTOS.Enrollment { GPA = GPA }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Since are currently returning an anonymous type in your `select` (as denoted by `new {}`), you can also change the type of `Response` to `var` so that you can access the property returned directly.  Note that in a single property access context, this is less efficient than the first option, but it is still possible and it is more useful when accessing multiple properties:

```
var Request = (...
               select new Enrollment { GPA = GPA }).SingleOrDefault();

var gpa = Request.GPA;
```

Comment: I have an existing model class named Enrollment with properties as stated above, are u saying i should create another class and give the same name Enrollment and include GPA as a property in it

Comment: Using database first , i made the Enrollment table a model already and thats d model im meant to return to the view

Comment: i tried what said but got an error Exception.  "The entity or complex type 'mydatabasetooModel.Enrollment' cannot be constructed in a linq to entities query

Comment: @LevethOlisa I've updated my answer to give you more options based on your comments.  You cannot create an entity model in a query, which is why you are receiving the error.  You'll need to change your approach to one of the three options I've given in my updated answer.

Comment: i tried the dtos method it but im not sending only gpa to view , im sending with the students own information and there some information related tables in the enrollment table, when used the dtos i couldnt access these member properties so as to display it